# Liability cap on car accident damages on public roads

Tags: law, policy, infrastructure

The scenario is this: a lower income person in an inexpensive automobile crashes into and totals a $200,000 Ferrari. The lower income person is at fault and doesn't have insurance and thus is bankrupted by paying for repairs on the Ferrari. Even if the person does have insurance, their insurer has to pay a huge amount in repairs and thus everyone's insurance has to be more expensive to "price in" these kinds of situations. It strikes me as at least plausible under certain political views of fairness that everyday people shouldn't have to pay extra in insurance or take on extra financial risk to drive on publicly funded roads just because other people choose to drive extraordinarily expensive cars.

One remedy would be to declare that if a car incurs more than say $50,000 in damages, then the person at fault (and their insurer) is only liable for $50,000 in damages. Does such a liability cap exist anywhere in the world? If not, are there other public policy solutions that have been proposed or implemented to address this issue?

Comment: How would that even work? What happens to the other $150k worth of damages? It still needs to be paid for. Also I think this might be better suited on the law site, as this isn't really a political policy question

Comment: I'm really not quite sure what you're asking, but this is exactly what  [Underinsured driver insurance](http://www.alllaw.com/articles/nolo/auto-accident/insurance-claim-underinsured-uninsured-drivers.html) is for.  If you're trying to make some kind of analogy to medical insurance (which is usually the only type of insurance that's actually relevant to Politics.SE), then it's so obtuse I can't see it.  If you're legitimately asking about car insurance, then I apologize for the assumption and please clarify the question.

Comment: The insurance does not cover only damages to the cars, but to the people. Given the scale of what civil liability may amount if someone is killed or disabled for live, I would say that the cost of the car is not that important when calculating the insurance primes. I would say that accidents with dead people/serious disability are way more usual than accidents involving so much car damages, by the simple motive that there are more people than ultra-expensive cars.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I guess that the idea would be that someone who owns a $200,000 car would auto-insure it for the remaining $150,000 (or would bet on no such accident happening).

Comment: Also, what would happen if the driver causes $15.000 of damages to 5 other different drivers each? Would those get paid less damages in order of keeping the $50,000 liability? That would lead to a lot of philosophical discussions (is a chain crash a single accident or a chain of different accidents?)

Comment: @Bobson lol it is actually about car insurance policy. Why is health insurance policy relevant to this site, but car insurance policy not? Car insurance is heavily regulated in all US states.

Comment: @lazarusL - It's not that it's not relevant, just that it's unusual.  Heath insurance is a hotly debated topic between the left and the right right now, while (AFAIK) there's no major controversy about car insurance.  And the question itself wasn't clear enough that I could tell you *weren't* trying to make a health care point.  Feel free to edit the question to clarify what policies you're asking about and I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: @Bobson I think if you're reading in a completely different subject in to a specific question; that's on you ;) I'm happy to help make the question more readable, what was confusing? Do you not understand how some people's choices to drive expensive cars could impose costs on others? Would it help if I took out the situation with the uninsured person (since as you said suing someone individually is generally not done) and just focus on the effect on everyone's premiums?

Answer (score 2):

> One remedy would be to declare that if a car incurs more than say $50,000 in damages, then the person at fault (and their insurer) is only liable for $50,000 in damages.

In the United States, only the insurer is sued for any significant amount of money unless the driver is well to do.  So as a practical matter, this is how it usually works for most people.  It's possible to sue someone into bankruptcy, but it is unprofitable.

Note that your remedy doesn't necessarily fix the problem.  If I get in an accident with a $500 car, then the maximum damage that I can do to the car is $500.  If I get in an accident with a $200,000 car, I can do anywhere from $0 to $200,000 worth of damage.  The $0 to $500 part of the range is the same for both, but what kind of accident only damages a car .25%?  If I do 25% damage to both, that's $125 for the cheap car and $50,000 for the expensive car.  Even with the cap, I'm still on the hook for almost $50,000 more in an accident with the expensive car.

A better solution would be to base the cap on the damage to the car and normalize to a multiple of the typical value.  For example, if the typical car was $20,000, the cap was $40,000, and you total the $200,000 car, you'd be on the hook for just $40,000.  If you do $100,000 of damage, you'd only be on the hook for $20,000.  The owner of the car would be responsible for the remaining $80,000 of damage.